# Estimating a probability given other probabilities from a prior

Tags: java, statistics, probability

I have a bunch of data coming in (calls to an automated callcenter) about whether or not a person buys a particular product, 1 for buy, 0 for not buy.

I want to use this data to create an estimated probability that a person will buy a particular product, but the problem is that I may need to do it with relatively little historical data about how many people bought/didn't buy that product.

A friend recommended that with Bayesian probability you can "help" your probability estimate by coming up with a "prior probability distribution", essentially this is information about what you expect to see, prior to taking into account the actual data.

So what I'd like to do is create a method that has something like this signature (Java):

```
double estimateProbability(double[] priorProbabilities, int buyCount, int noBuyCount);
```

priorProbabilities is an array of probabilities I've seen for previous products, which this method would use to create a prior distribution for this probability.  buyCount and noBuyCount are the actual data specific to this product, from which I want to estimate the probability of the user buying, given the data and the prior.  This is returned from the method as a double.

I don't need a mathematically perfect solution, just something that will do better than a uniform or flat prior (ie. *probability = buyCount / (buyCount+noBuyCount)*).  Since I'm far more familiar with source code than mathematical notation, I'd appreciate it if people could use code in their explanation.

Comment: really cool problem, and I think I know the exact Bayesian solution, but it still will take a while to code (would you mind executable pseudocode, AKA Python source? I'm a tad rusty with Java...;-).

Comment: Alex, yes - Python or pseudo-python is absolutely fine!

Comment: i don't think this is a programming problem per se; it is a theoretical math question wrapped in a java method stub.

Comment: @Steven, what is with the hatred for anything vaguely involving math here?  Math and programming are closely related.  Many programming problems have a mathematical component.  If anything related to math is impermissible on SO, then I'm sorry to say that SO will be a much less useful, and less interesting website.

Comment: I agree with @Steven A. Lowe; not directly programming related

Comment: @sanity: How is this question any different from a "plz send teh codez" question? You've essentially provided a method stub and asked SO to solve your problem for you. And it's a math problem, in the sense of inventing or researching a mathematical technique. This is not a programming question. Furthermore, what is the point of arguing with the people that are trying to help you? With the information you've given, uniform probability is it. ARL will help if you have something else to correlate with.

Comment: and -1 for arguing with people trying to help you.

Comment: @Steven: Firstly: I've asked for help with a problem, that is what SO is for, right?  Secondly, you are asserting that the fact that something involves mathematics means that its not a programming problem.  I refute that assertion, mathematics and programming are not mutually exclusive.  A programming problem can also be a math problem, and vice-versa.  Thirdly, the point of arguing with people that are trying to help me is that they have misinterpreted my question.  Its reasonable to point out their error.  Fourthly, its not uniform probability.  See Alex Martelli's solution.

Comment: @Steven: And as for the "and -1 for arguing with people trying to help you" - I'd say that correcting those that have misinterpreted a question is completely reasonable.  Alex interpreted the question correctly without clarification, so clearly the flaw was not in the question itself.  Worse, you've just admitted to voting down a question solely to punish the question's author.  I really hope for SO's sake that your behavior is atypical.

Comment: @Mitch, I'm very concerned that the standard you are applying for what is an acceptable question on SO would lead to a much less useful website.  What questions are "directly" related to programming seems to be an extremely subjective judgment call.

Comment: @sanity: Downvotes with comments help you learn. I see three ways to interpret this question: (1) As a programming question, amounting to a homework question with no effort expended, (2) As a programming question equivalent to "plz send teh codez", and/or (3) As a mathematical theory question, which is the least offensive yet least applicable kind of question for SO. I have flagged this question for moderator attention, and will happily retract all and apologize if directed to do so. Will you do the same?

Comment: @steven: "Downvotes with comments help you learn" and your response to (1) and (2) are extremely rude and patronizing. I've read your profile, you should read mine and then explain what gives you the right to condescend. (3) you have repeatedly failed to explain why a question that involves math is inappropriate for SO.  My contention is that math is intimately related to programming, and the two subjects are not mutually exclusive.  Re: moderator attention, I would be interested in 3rd party feedback on this conversation, but it won't change my opinion, I've done my best to be polite.

Comment: @sanity: I have read your profile and respect your work, and I'm sorry if I come across as rude/patronizing/condescending - it's late and I don't intend disrespect. (1) and (2) are observations, not accusations; some rewording might clear it up. As to your specific question (3), you've been a member of this site as long as i have, and have presumably read the FAQ. I would suggest that PlanetMath would be more appropriate for a math question than SO, as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321618/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Comment: @sanity: and downvote removed as an olive branch ;-)

Comment: [MODERATOR] this question appears to have "kicked off"; re the comments - yes, there is a strong link between mathematics and programming (indeed, I myself hold a maths degree): in both cases we are often trying to solve a problem involving data. It is *entirely appropriate* to ask for help with a programming question that has a strong math element... **BUT**, it would be better received if the question was a bit more than an empty method stub - that doesn't exactly show of an attempt nor a *specific* problem.

Comment: [MODERATOR] In the current state, I *personally* wouldn't vote to close, but I also probably wouldn't do much more than reference the overall algorithm, for example on wikipedia or similar. There is some... "unnecessary" angst in some of the comments; lets just keep it civil, people. Re "(1) and (2) are extremely rude and patronizing" - that seems overly sensitive. They are valid interpretations (that could be more delicately phrased), given a question with a named algorithm and an empty method stub.

Comment: [MODERATOR] I'm glad that the question itself has been answered satisfactorily; the main flash-point here seems to have been perceived rudeness (in both directions). Reading this cold, I don't believe anybody is being deliberately or blatantly obnoxious; a lot of pain here could have been saved by (when reading something that irritates) taking a deep breath, stepping back, and reading it again slowly. Things are often not meant in quiet the same tone/meaning/etc as is originally perceived on the first reading.

Comment: [MODERATOR] There isn't anything much to be gained from any intervention at this point; the question has an answer, and the thread is now getting cold. Can I suggest we all move on and try to be more... "generous in our interpretation" of peoples comments? If I've missed the point, please e-mail me (see profile).

Comment: IMHO the question does not smell at all like "do my math homework for me". There is an actual real-world problem that the poster is trying to solve with code, and he has an idea that Bayesian statistics could be the way to go but has no experience with it - he even says that he isn't interested in a mathematically perfect Bayesian answer, just something that will adequately solve the problem. He posted a method stub because that's a really clear way of communicating what the inputs and outputs of the problem are.

Comment: @Steven, I also regret the conversation's descent into personal sniping, and accept that I may have jumped to the worst possible interpretation of your comments, probably also a product of it being late. However I still don't agree with your core assertion that this type of question doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: @[Marc Gravell]: Thanks for your comment. I don't completely agree, but Jouni K. Seppänen provided the response that I would have, so I'll leave it at that. Anyway, I appreciate you're providing a "cooler head" in the discussion. I hope SO continues to be a place where you can ask questions, without having to spend too much energy defending how or why you are asking the question. I've seen other UGC websites die because of a propensity to descend into such meta-discussions (specifically kuro5hin.org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the Bayesian computation and one example/test:

```
def estimateProbability(priorProbs, buyCount, noBuyCount):
  # first, estimate the prob that the actual buy/nobuy counts would be observed
  # given each of the priors (times a constant that's the same in each case and
  # not worth the effort of computing;-)`
  condProbs = [p**buyCount * (1.0-p)**noBuyCount for p in priorProbs]
  # the normalization factor for the above-mentioned neglected constant
  # can most easily be computed just once
  normalize = 1.0 / sum(condProbs)
  # so here's the probability for each of the prior (starting from a uniform
  # metaprior)
  priorMeta = [normalize * cp for cp in condProbs]
  # so the result is the sum of prior probs weighed by prior metaprobs
  return sum(pm * pp for pm, pp in zip(priorMeta, priorProbs))

def example(numProspects=4):
  # the a priori prob of buying was either 0.3 or 0.7, how does it change
  # depending on how 4 prospects bought or didn't?
  for bought in range(0, numProspects+1):
    result = estimateProbability([0.3, 0.7], bought, numProspects-bought)
    print 'b=%d, p=%.2f' % (bought, result)

example()
```

output is:

```
b=0, p=0.31
b=1, p=0.36
b=2, p=0.50
b=3, p=0.64
b=4, p=0.69
```

which agrees with my by-hand computation for this simple case.  Note that the probability of  buying, by definition, will always be between the lowest and the highest among the set of priori probabilities; if that's not what you want you might want to introduce a little fudge by introducing two "pseudo-products", one that nobody will ever buy (p=0.0), one that anybody will always buy (p=1.0) -- this gives more weight to actual observations, scarce as they may be, and less to statistics about past products.  If we do that here, we get:

```
b=0, p=0.06
b=1, p=0.36
b=2, p=0.50
b=3, p=0.64
b=4, p=0.94
```

Intermediate levels of fudging (to account for the unlikely but not impossible chance that this new product may be worse than any one ever previously sold, or better than any of them) can easily be envisioned (give lower weight to the artificial 0.0 and 1.0 probabilities, by adding a vector priorWeights to `estimateProbability`'s arguments).

This kind of thing is a substantial part of what I do all day, now that I work developing applications in Business Intelligence, but I just can't get enough of it...!-)

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'm glad someone appreciated the question :-)  This definitely looks right but I won't be able to examine your answer in-detail until tomorrow.  That being said, I'm happy to accept your answer for now :-)

Comment: By all means, check it out (transcoding to Java as needed, but do consider Jython for quick and dirty tests) and get back to me, either on this question or a new one, I'm at least as keen as you to get this working just right!-)  *long live Bayes...!-)*

Answer (score 2):

A really simple way of doing this without any difficult math is to increase buyCount and noBuyCount artificially by adding virtual customers that either bought or didn't buy the product. You can tune how much you believe in each particular prior probability in terms of how many virtual customers you think it is worth.

In pseudocode:

```
def estimateProbability(priorProbs, buyCount, noBuyCount, faithInPrior=None):
    if faithInPrior is None: faithInPrior = [10 for x in buyCount]
    adjustedBuyCount = [b + p*f for b,p,f in 
                                zip(buyCount, priorProbs, faithInPrior]
    adjustedNoBuyCount = [n + (1-p)*f for n,p,f in 
                                zip(noBuyCount, priorProbs, faithInPrior]
    return [b/(b+n) for b,n in zip(adjustedBuyCount, adjustedNoBuyCount]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you're trying to do is [Association Rule Learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule). I don't have time right now to provide you with any code, but I will point you in the direction of [WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) which is a fantastic open source data mining toolkit for Java. You should find plenty of interesting things there that will help you solve your problem.

Comment: This is interesting, but I don't see how it solves the specific problem I describe :-/

Comment: +1 to counter ignorance/laziness; this is a very good suggestion

Comment: Steven, I've read the linked article on ARL in its entirety.  Perhaps you could explain how this suggestion solves the specific problem I outline?

Comment: @sanity: ARL will help if you have something else to correlate with.

Comment: @Steven, I'm not trying to correlate with any additional metadata.  I think you (and n3rd) are trying to solve a different problem to the one presented in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, the best you could do is use the uniform distribution, unless you have some clue regarding the distribution. Or are you talking about making a relationship between this products and products previously bought by the same person in the Amazon Fashion "people who buy this product also buy..." ??

Comment: The clue regarding the distribution is provided in the priorProbabilities parameter to the method.  This is a list of purchase probabilities which we found for other products - and it can be used (hopefully) to come up with a prior distribution for this product's purchase probability.

Comment: IMHO, you need to correlate the buy or not buy with some other parameter (for example, age, gender. country, time of year, time of the day, other products purchased, etc). Otherwise the best information you have is the uniform distribution using the accumulated purchase rate.

Comment: Really that is all I'm looking for at this point.  Normally I would be looking to correlate with metadata like age and gender, but the problem is that there simply isn't enough data for that.

My challenge here is to come up with the most accurate probability possible of making a purchase based on a minimal amount of data (perhaps only a few hundred calls, where the typical purchase rate is around 5-10%).

Partitioning the data based on age or gender simply isn't possible because there isn't enough data for this.

Comment: @sanity: then you must use the uniform distribution, anything else falls in the domain of magic. If 20 in 100 people have bought, the probability of a new person buying is 1/5, nothing else.

Comment: @tekBlues: I don't think so.  The actual discovered probabilities for other products form a prior distribution of where we'd expect this probability to lie.  For example, if all other probabilities are between 5% and 15%, then a uniform distribution clearly isn't appropriate.